# How can I open more than one cmd frames at the saame time and use different codes in them

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am basically hosting 4 node.js projects at the same time and want a batch file to run them all using cmd but I cant open more than one cmd using only one bat file or cant open them all using another bat file so I have to manually make new bat files and edit them everytime I make a new project

```
cmd.exe
cmd.exe
cmd /k "title hello & color E0"
cmd /k "title hi & color E7"
```

this is one of my desperete tries, ıt only performs firt line, then the second when I write exit, third line after the next exit and so on. Can u pls help me

Comment: It is batch, the next command runs when the previous is done. So force it to run at the same time. Use `start` (see `start /?`) or do `cmd || cmd2 || cmd3` etc.

Comment: As well as the above advice, I'd invite you to also read the output resulting for opening a Command Prompt window, typing `cmd /?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key. Everything you need is explained in the output from those two commands. _If you cannot understand that information you probably shouldn't be using a more complex tool like `node.js`!_

Answer (score 0):

To give you a better representation of using `start` in my comment, here is an example:

```
title This is the original prompt & color A7
start cmd /k "title prompt 1 & color B7"
start cmd /k "title prompt 2 & color C7"
start cmd /k "title prompt 3 & color D7"
start cmd /k "title prompt 4 & color E7"
```